# Why does BluetoothGattCallback's onCharacteristicWrite have status 128 "GATT_NO_RESOURCE"?

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, nrf52

I am trying to write to the LED characteristic of a (Client) nRF52 DK from an Android application (Server). I can read the value from the characteristic fine and I also receive a callback. When a write is attempted the callback occurs and the status is 128 for "GATT_NO_RESOURCE".

0df51501-2e2c-4bca-bf8a-94ff0ae14b0e is the uuid for the LED characteristic.

[NRF Connect showing the DK services and LED characteristic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acpct.jpg)

NRF Connect can write to the DK after I trigger beginReliableWrite and executeReliableWrite. My current application cannot.

My goal is to write to the DK with the phone application and control the states of the LEDs by sending 0x00 to turn them off or 0xFF to turn them (4 in total)on.

[My Application showing the DK services and LED characteristic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxU4Q.jpg)

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer without knowing your android application. Could you add some code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.